# Activity crash oncall

Tags: android

I am calling an activity from MainActivity.java, but it crashes. below is the logcat error. didn't understood where is the actual problem, all the naming are correct and activities and layout are correctly named, no compile time errors.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.s2s.doupnow, PID: 26707
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.s2s.doupnow/com.s2s.doupnow.VideoPlayActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class TextView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class TextView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at com.s2s.doupnow.VideoDescriptionFragment.onCreateView(VideoDescriptionFragment.java:16)
at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4797)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:41)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:692)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at com.s2s.doupnow.VideoPlayActivity.onCreate(VideoPlayActivity.java:61)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

activity_videoplay.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_videoplayer"
        android:name="com.s2s.doupnow.VideoPlayerFragment"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_videodescription"
        android:name="com.s2s.doupnow.VideoDescriptionFragment"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_videodescription.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fcfcfc" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fragmentvideodescription_titletextview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragmentvideodescription_viewstextview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_file_download"
                android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_gap"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_thumb_up"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_gap"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_share"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/textview_description"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml file

Comment: show you VideoPlayActivity's xml file

Comment: The error posted is related to the `TextView` while inflating. Could you please add you xml file ?

Comment: add all fragment xml

Comment: we need xml file which has textview as your error log says

Comment: fragment_videodescription.xml file is having the TextView

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, actually the problem was with the drawable files, the drawable files were in v24 format, deleted and created again and the error went. thnx